# Get all the records where it does not exist in 2nd LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I want to select all the records where `FeeZoneID` doesn't exist in second linq output.

I know it can easily done in SQL using NOT IN(....) but i do it in LINQ???

```
from d in FeeZones
where d.FeeZoneID !(from b in FeeZoneSchemes
    where b.FeeSchemeID == 1
    join c in FeeZones on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
    select c)
 select d
```

In my C# class this is how I am doing :

```
   public IList<FeeZone> _LQ_GetAllAvaliableFeeZoneForGivenFeeSchemeID(int FeeSchemeID)
    {
       using(var db = new QualificationContext())
       {
           var query = (from d in db.FeeZone
                        where (!(from b in db.FeeZoneScheme
                               where b.FeeSchemeID == FeeSchemeID
                               join c in db.FeeZone on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
                               select c).Contains(d.FeeZoneID))
                       select d).ToList();



           return query.ToList();
       }

    }
```

And this is the error :
[image]
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try is as below.

```
from d in FeeZones
where (!(from b in FeeZoneSchemes where b.FeeSchemeID == 1
    join c in FeeZones on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
    select c.FeeZoneID).Contains(d.FeeZoneID))
 select d
```

Comment: no i am getting error i have update my code above please... many thanks

Comment: it return me all the records instead of filtered records i just debug in visual studio...

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
var query = from d in FreeZones
            let unwantedZonesIds = FeeZoneSchemes.Where(b => b.FreeSchemeID == 1)
                                                 .Select(b => b.FreeZoneID)
            where !unwantedZonesIds.Contains(d.FreeZoneID)
            select d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Any` instead of `Contains`

```
var query = (from d in db.FeeZone
                    where (!((from b in db.FeeZoneScheme
                           where b.FeeSchemeID == FeeSchemeID
                           join c in db.FeeZone on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
                           select c).Any(x => x.FeeZoneID ==d.FeeZoneID))
                   select d).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query .

```
        IList<FeeZones> lst = new List<FeeZones>() { new FeeZones() { FeeZoneID = 1 }, new FeeZones() { FeeZoneID =2 } };
        IList<FeeZoneSchemes> lstnew = new List<FeeZoneSchemes>(){new FeeZoneSchemes(){FeeSchemeID=1,FeeZoneID=1}};


        var res = (from d in lst
                   where !(
                       from c in lstnew 
                       join f in lst on c.FeeZoneID equals f.FeeZoneID
                       where c.FeeSchemeID == 1 && c.FeeZoneID == f.FeeZoneID 
                       select f.FeeZoneID
                   ).Contains(d.FeeZoneID)
                   select d).ToList();
```

or You can use the Sql way of exists query like below.

```
 var res = (from d in lst
                   where !(
                       from c in lstnew 
                       where c.FeeSchemeID == 1 && c.FeeZoneID == d.FeeZoneID 
                       select c
                   ).Any()
                   select d).ToList();
```